# Vimscript code review: specific case

Tags: discussion

Today I stumbled on [How to show git branch in statusline?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20542/10604). The question's title is a bit misleading—it actually wants a review of current code. Seeing that it was a code review, I was unsure how to proceed, but figured I would leave a first-draft answer and then ask on meta.

While drafting this question, I found and read [How does this site feel about code review questions?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-does-this-site-feel-about-code-review-questions). It argues for allowing such Q&As.

I want to clarify for this specific case that I am following site procedure (so that I can rest easier in my answer)—effectively, that the linked meta is still community consensus.

---

(I for one would love it to be, since I don't spend as much time on CR either, and [vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) only has [11 questions on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimscript).)

Comment: Even if the meta question you linked is 3 years old I don't see a reason why our consensus would have changed: We didn't have a lot of code review questions since then so I think that allowing them doesn't really change how our site works. I think your answer is great and definitely follows our rules :)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but are you (plural) saying that, as long as the question is about Vim, I can use vi.stackexchange as I'd use codereview.stackexchange?

Comment: @Enlico sort of—I think a slightly narrower definition (say, vimscript and lua specific to neovim, though there are also other ways to configure and program vim) might be more appropriate? But generally yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [comments](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/vimscript-code-review-specific-case#comment1143_1482), posting reviews of code seems fine. Glad to hear.

> I don’t see a reason why our consensus would have changed
>
> your answer [...] definitely follows our rules
>
> —statox